# Memory Error when attempting to load jpeg from resource file Delphi XE7 / OSX

Tags: delphi, jpeg, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, timage

I found the code to do the following on this site, so thanks
However the line "logo.Bitmap.LoadFromStream( MyRs);"

Access Violation - some kind of memory error I assume.

I used Project | Resources and Images ... to add the Jpeg

Is this a problem with the resource not being linked in, or rather my code?

Thanks :)

```
uses
  Classes, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Objects;

procedure MyProvedure();
var
     logo  : TImage;
     MyRS  : TResourceStream;
begin
  MyRS := TResourceStream.Create( HInstance, 'logo_1', RT_RCDATA );
  try
      logo.Bitmap.LoadFromStream( MyRs);
  finally
    MyRS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ask yourself what the lifetime of `logo` is?

Comment: This procedure prints out a PDF with logo (the bitmap) - so the lifetime is ok - so long as it is first created!! (as Ari0nah states) - I then free it in the finally block. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create image before using it:

```
logo := TImage.Create(nil);
```